# Python simulate media keys

Tags: python, media, python-3.7

How to make Python (3.7) manipulate any media player currently working on Windows?

I want to get functionality similar to media keys on keyboard, for example:

- play_pause.py script which will play or pause music on Spotify or movie in media player (whatever is currently playing).
- play_next.py script which will play next song/movie etc.

To clarify: I don't want Python to virtually press actual media keys on keyboard. I would like to get the functionality of such keys so it might work even without keyboard connected to PC.

Comment: `Is there any way to make Python (3.7) manipulate any media player currently working on Windows?` Yea probably

Comment: I think you can do it with Python. I tried this C# code(without keyboard) and it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21236001/7128891
Maybe I will try to do it using Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use [`win32api.keybd_event`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__keybd_event_meth.html) from [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32).

For example,  install *pywin32*:

```
pip install pywin32
```

And try play/pause - should work without keyboard:

```
import win32api
from win32con import VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY

win32api.keybd_event(VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0)
```

Virtual-Key Codes: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) and [here](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/master/win32/Lib/win32con.py).

NOTE:
At [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) about *keybd_event* function, you can see message: *"**Note** This function has been superseded. Use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead"*.
So if you want/need to use *SendInput*, you probably need to use [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ctypes.html). I suggest you to check the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11910555/7128891). I've tried that code too and it works. If you need any further help, let me know.